# How does the Transformer Model Compute Self Attention?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model, attention-model

In the transformer model, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf there is self-attention which is computed using softmax on `Query (Q)` and `Key (K)` vectors:

I am trying to understand the matrix multiplications:

```
Q = batch_size x seq_length x embed_size

K = batch_size x seq_length x embed_size

QK^T = batch_size x seq_length x seq_length

Softmax QK^T = Softmax (batch_size x seq_length x seq_length)
```

How is the softmax computed since there are `seq_length x seq_length` values per batch element?

A reference to Pytorch computation will be very helpful.

Cheers!

Comment: This resource might be of help (and it contains code in PyTorch) https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html

Answer (score 3):

> How is the softmax computed since there are `seq_length x seq_length` values per batch element?

The softmax is performed on w.r.t the last axis (`torch.nn.Softmax(dim=-1)(tensor)` where `tensor` is of shape `batch_size x seq_length x seq_length`) to get the probability of attending to every element for each element in the input sequence.

---

Let's assume, we have a text sequence "Thinking Machines", so we have a matrix of shape "2 x 2" (where `seq_length = 2`) after performing `QK^T`.

I am using the following illustration ([reference](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/)) to explain self-attention computation. As you know, first scaled-dot-product is performed `QK^T/square_root(d_k)` and then softmax is computed for each sequence element.

Here, `Softmax` is performed for the first sequence element "Thinking". The raw score of `14 and 12` is turned into a probability of `0.88 and 0.12` by doing softmax. These probability indicates that the token "Thinking" would attend itself with 88% probability, and the token "Machines"  with 12% probability. Similarly, the attention probability is computed for the token "Machines" too.

[image]

---

**Note**. I strongly suggest reading this excellent [article](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/) on Transformer. For implementation, you can take a look at [OpenNMT](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/blob/master/onmt/modules/multi_headed_attn.py#L202).

Answer (score 2):

The QKᵀ multiplication is a batched matrix multiplication -- it's doing a separate `seq_length x embed_size` by `embed_size x seq_length` multiplication `batch_size` times. Each one gives a result of size `seq_length x seq_length`, which is how we end up with QKᵀ having the shape `batch_size x seq_length x seq_length`.

[Gabriela Melo's suggested resource](https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html) uses the following PyTorch code for this operation:

```
torch.matmul(query, key.transpose(-2, -1))
```

This works because `torch.matmul` does a batched matrix multiplication when an input has at least 3 dimensions (see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.matmul).